How can I run an Irfanview batch script in a for loop inside a .bat file?
I'm trying to write a .bat file that will

extract all .cbz archive files in current directory
convert all jpgs in the resulting directories into pngs with a max width/height of 750/560, by using an Irfanview batch script
delete the jpgs from the directories (keeping only the pngs)

This is what I have so far (the echo and pause are for testing):
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM Step 1: Extract .cbz files into directories
for %%i in (*.cbz) do (
    tar -xf "%%i"
)

pause

REM Step 2: IrfanView
for /d %%d in (*) do (
    set "CurrentDir=%%~dpd%%d"
    echo ""%ProgramFiles%\IrfanView\i_view64.exe" "!CurrentDir!\*.jpg" /resize=(750,560) /aspectratio /resample /convert="!CurrentDir!\*.png"
    pause
    "%ProgramFiles%\IrfanView\i_view64.exe" "!CurrentDir!\*.jpg" /resize=(750,560) /aspectratio /resample /convert="!CurrentDir!\*.png"
    del "!CurrentDir!\*.jpg"
    pause
)
pause
endlocal

If I remove the line in which IrfanView is called, the rest of it works fine (the .cbz files get extracted into folders filled with jpgs, the "echo" line is displayed, then the jpgs are deleted). But if that line is in there, it causes the entire "for" loop to not work, not even the "echo".
I know that the "CurrentDir" variable is being assigned correctly, because the echo works. Here's an example of the echo if the IrfanView line is removed (with the batch script in D:\testIrfanview):
""C:\Program Files\IrfanView\i_view64.exe" "D:\testIrfanview\cbzFile\*.jpg" /resize=(750,560) /aspectratio /resample /convert="D:\testIrfanview\cbzFile\*.png"
The IrfanView syntax seems to be correct, because I can put the following .bat file into one of the extracted directories with the jpgs, and if I run it, the jpgs get converted into small pngs just as intended:
set CurrentDir=%~dp0
    if not exist "%CurrentDir%png" mkdir "%CurrentDir%png"
    "%ProgramFiles%\IrfanView\i_view64.exe" "%CurrentDir%*.jpg" /resize=(750,560) /aspectratio /resample /convert="%CurrentDir%png\*.png"

But why doesn't it work inside the for loop?
If anyone's wondering what this is for, it's to make filmstrip (DiaFilm) .cbz files viewable on the Miyoo Mini V4's OnionOS, since the file reader can only view pngs.
EDIT:
I partly fixed it by changing "%ProgramFiles%\IrfanView\i_view64.exe" to ^"C:\Program^ Files\IrfanView\i_view64.exe"
Then the next problem was that it deleted most of the jpgs before it could make all the PNGs, so I had to separate that line into another for loop at the end, making the final code be this:
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM Step 1: Extract .cbz files into directories
for %%i in (*.cbz) do tar -xf "%%i"

REM pause

REM Step 2: IrfanView, make pngs to fit Miyoo Mini V4 screen resolution
for /d %%d in (*) do (
    set "CurrentDir=%%~dpd%%d"
    ^"C:\Program^ Files\IrfanView\i_view64.exe" "!CurrentDir!\*.jpg" /resize=(750,560) /aspectratio /resample /convert="!CurrentDir!\*.png"
)
REM pause
REM Step 3: delete the jpgs
for /d %%d in (*) do (
    set "CurrentDir=%%~dpd%%d"
    del "!CurrentDir!\*.jpg"
)
REM pause
endlocal

That works for .cbz files that have a directory inside them in which the jpg files are. However, I've discovered that many .cbz files just have the jpg files inside with no directory.
EDIT2: The text below is not relevant to the initial issue, which was fixed, so please ignore it. I'm leaving it here, but I'll ask a new question if I can't figure it out myself.
So I replaced
for %%i in (*.cbz) do tar -xf "%%i"
with
for %%i in (*.cbz) do (
    mkdir "%%~ni"
    tar -xf "%%i" -C "%%~ni"
)

which didn't work. It created the directory with the same name as the .cbz file, but didn't extract any jpgs into it.
I added an echo and pause statement, and got the following:
tar -xf "Соленый снег.cbz.cbz" -C "Соленый снег.cbz"
tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open '??????? ????.cbz.cbz'

So it seems to be a unicode support issue. Doing a search, it seems that a fix for the Windows tar was released in December, but hasn't made its way over to Windows yet, so it would be better to use something other than tar...
I also tried the GNU tar from git-for-windows:
^"C:\Program^ Files\Git\usr\bin\tar.exe" -xf "%%i" -C "%%~ni"
but it gave me the error "This does not look like a tar archive"
And 7-Zip:
^"C:\Program^ Files\7-Zip\7z.exe "%%i" -o "%%~ni"
e.g.
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" "Лочинское ущелье.cbz.cbz" -o "Лочинское ущелье.cbz"
but got:
Command Line Error:
Unsupported command:
______.cbz.cbz -o _________

Again, seems like an issue with unicode...

What is your question? Your title suggests its something about using a particular command within a for loop, which has already been answered. However the body text appears to suggest that you're looking for an off topic software recommendation! We expect just one question per submission, and we do not provide a rolling project support service. It is quite unfair on the person who has answered the initial question, to now have a seemingly incomplete solution.

Magoo's answer did not seem to be what was causing the problem - rather, it was the spaces in "Program Files", which I discovered myself after posting the question, and posted in my edit above. I guess I should have marked the question as "closed" and asked a new question for the next issue that came up. My apologies.

Your code as posted absolutely does suffer from the issue highlighted and answered by Magoo. Without the fix they have offered, whatever else you think may have been an issue is not an answer to your titled question.

/resize=(750,560) in your "%ProgramFiles%\IrfanView\i_view64.exe" line needs to be /resize=(750,560^)
The ) terminates the parenthisised code block, generating a /aspectratio was unexpected at this time. error message. The caret escapes the ), telling cmd that the ) is simply a character, without its special meaning.

Thanks! Hmm, I think I never had that problem, though. I did some more tinkering since I posted the question and posted the version that worked above. Unfortunately, I discovered that for many .cbz files I need to make a directory with the same name and extract the jpgs into it, and the code I wrote to do that didn't work...

The problem I had in my initial question was fixed by changing "%ProgramFiles%\IrfanView\i_view64.exe" to ^"C:\Program^ Files\IrfanView\i_view64.exe" (I edited my answer above to show the full code).
Now the code worked as long as the .cbz files in the directory had ASCII file names and a single folder immediately inside them instead of jpgs.
I then had another issue due to being unable to use tar to extract .cbz files with a unicode filename, but that's a topic for another question...
